# How to control widget after listview in stack

Tags: flutter, dart

I build a flutter app with ads as a carousel slider as a bottom layer  of the stack widget, and I have I list view in the top layer of the stack widget
and when the list is scrolled vertically it overlays the ads on the screen.

now I have a problem with the carousel slider, I can't scroll it manually and I can't click any

how to solve it?

demo code:

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            autoPlay: true,
          ),
          items: imgList
              .map((item) => Center(
                      child: Image.network(
                    item,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )))
              .toList(),
        ),
        ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 210),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(
                    'ITEM $index',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ))
      ],
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to lay your widgets out.
If you want to keep the ads persistent (not to scroll away with list) then keep the layout like :

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      CarouselSlider(),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: I don’t want to change stack widget

Answer (score 0):

Using positioned widget inside stack you can easily position the widgets.
Maybe this will help you.

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          bottom: 250,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(
                      'ITEM $index',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 8,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CarouselSlider(
                items: imgList.map((i) {
                  return Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                              child: Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                              onTap: () {
                                print("hey");
                              }));
                    },
                  );
                }).toList(),
                options: CarouselOptions(),
              )),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not helpful.

Comment: "I can't scroll it manually and I can't click any" is this the problem?

Comment: I updated the  CarouselSlider() onClick event on my code please check it out thus it works for you :)